# Alignment of borders of table using bootstrap table-bordered class is not proper when scrollbar appears

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Alignment of borders of table using bootstrap table-bordered class is not proper when scrollbar appears, Itried many workarounds, but problem is still there, can someone please help?

Here is my hbs:

```
<title>UI</title>
```

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table style="border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc" class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;" width="15%"></th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;" width="15%">Pending</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;" width="15%">Done</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody style="display:block;height:164px;overflow:auto;">
                                <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                </tr>
                <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                </tr>
                <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                </tr>
                <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                </tr>
                <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                </tr>
                <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                </tr>
                     </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Alignment is not proper: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdcea.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, the major cause of the issue of border not aligning is `table-layout:fixed;` on the `thead`. You can run it an see

```html
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >           
           
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <table style="border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc" class="table table-bordered">
                                        <thead style="display:table;width:100%;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="text-align:center;" width="15%"></th>
                                                <th style="text-align:center;" width="15%">Pending</th>
                                                <th style="text-align:center;" width="15%">Done</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody style="display:table;height:164px;overflow:auto; table-layout:fixed;">
                                            <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                                <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                                <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                                <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                                <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                                <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                                                <td style="text-align:center;">Task 1</td>
                                                <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try it exactly as I pasted?? here is a fiddle check it out https://fiddle.jshell.net/ms5qb87m/

Comment: You can also run the snippet and see if that is what you are looking for